# Can't run function on variable-length argument array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I am trying to perform a function on my arguments, which is variable length. I can't seem to run any function on my arguments array, including sort.

```
function findKeyFromNotes()
    {
         var notes = arguments.slice(); 
         return notes;  
    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: arguments.slice is not a function
```

Thanks,
Nakul

Comment: How are you calling `findKeyFromNotes`?

Comment: @ScottHunter it doesn't matter, the `arguments` object doesn't have a `.slice()` method.

Comment: `var realArray = [].slice.call(arguments);`

Comment: @StackSlave that's a very common pattern, but it's not the best idea because leaking the `arguments` object makes it basically impossible to optimize the function (because `arguments` does weird things).

Comment: @Pointy Implementations still have not learned to special-case `call` and `slice`?

Comment: @Bergi the problem is that `arguments` provides an alias for actual parameters, so it's extremely hard to know what a called function will do via the passed-in object. Like, a function that's passed an `arguments` object reference can change an actual parameter in the calling function.

Comment: @Bergi now of course it'd be possible to detect the specific case of doing the `.slice()` trick.

Comment: @Pointy Strict mode has solved the problem of aliasing parameters. I think the current performance overhead (compared to the [oft-repeated recommendation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#32-leaking-arguments) too use a loop for copying into an array) comes from having to reify the arguments as an actual object that can be passed around. But as the notice at the top of that page says, even that appears to be outdated (since long).

Comment: @Bergi so to be clear, in strict code assignments to `arguments` elements do not alter the corresponding parameters?

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that happens in sloppy mode only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern JavaScript, you can use the spread syntax to collect all arguments into a single array value:

```
function findKeyFromNotes(... notes) {
  // notes will be an array
}
```

In "traditional" JavaScript the best thing to do would be:

```
function findKeyFromNotes() {
  var notes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) notes[i] = arguments[i];
  // now notes is a plain array
}
```

Comment: The common use of `.slice()` to  convert `arguments` to an array is kind-of a bad idea because it seriously impedes JIT optimization.

Comment: My comment does not apply to "strict" mode code however.